# primeng p-calender time only issue

Tags: angular, primeng

I am new to angular2 , i have been using primeng p-calender for time input 24 hour format. 
can anyone hep with this formatting

my HTML template code :

```
      <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="branchBO.endTime"  [timeOnly]="true"  timeZone = "" timeFormat="HH:mm" formControlName="endTime" hourFormat="24"   required ></p-calendar>
```

in my component.ts

alert(endTime) returns me

> Sat Apr 01 2017 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

console.log(endTime ) prints

> 2017-04-01T03:30:00.866Z

My expected output value is 09:00 or whatever user input is. Looking for solutions.

Comment: Your expected output already in component.

Comment: yeah i expected output but my expected result is not correct .Any Good reason why mark negative?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the component a new date from 0 like this `new Date(0)` then it would provide you a time in hours from the beginning of unix time when you use the component. If you give it a `new Date()` it's giving the actual date time.
Then you just need to format it when you want to use it or if you want to save it in you database, send it as a unix timestamp by exemple...

Comment: I know this was posted 1 year before but I respond at it for posterity ;)